# How can I stop my Alaskan Malemute's scrape behaviour after peeing?

Tags: dogs, toilet-training

How can I stop my Alaskan Malemute's scrape behaviour after peeing? It causes so much damage to our lawn/grass.

Comment: Have you tried [dog boots](https://www.google.com/search?q=dog+boots) No idea if it would work, but it might protect the lawn.

Comment: I recently started clicking my dog when he does so, eventually that will be a cool trick!

Answer (score 1):

I would try training him that when he goes he should come to you immediately then he will get a reward. It will only be possible if he is always supervised because it is just a natural behavior. Most dogs do it after going to the bathroom but some do it more than others. I do know people who have mostly trained it out of their dogs but they still put a word to it as their dog is going.